# How to track the GPS coordinates as user walks, from xamarin.forms for ios platform

Tags: ios, xamarin, gps, geolocation, xamarin.forms

I just went through this [link](http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/multitasking/track_significant_location_change/)

to track GPS co-ordinates of current location as User walks with a xamarin.forms app (iOS platforms)

But I could not find how to do it, as I am born new to xamarin.forms,

Can we do this in xamarin.forms or should I Create a xamarin ios project?

Any links/tutorials to track the user location through xamarin.forms for iOS platfomrs would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: The link you are referring to has the title 'Track **Significant** Location Change'. From what you are asking, a walking user, you want even a smal change in GPS location. This tutorial provides you a way of tracking large changes in GPS signal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We used [Xamarin-Forms-Labs](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs) to do this. Works perfect with Xamarin.Forms on all platforms.

For more information: [Geolocator](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/Geolocator)

Answer (score 6):

The [Geolocator Plugin for Xamarin and Windows](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.Geolocator/) is also a great way to deal with location services (such as fetching a user's current location) in a cross-platform manner.

The API is literally a few lines, and is as simple as calling one method. If you wish to do more advanced things like track a user's location in the background (use case: maps app), you can do that as well.

You can learn more about it [in this blog post from Xamarin](https://blog.xamarin.com/geolocation-for-ios-android-and-windows-made-easy/).

Comment: This is the better way to do it.