# How can I set a location and direction arrow in Xamarin forms map?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am developing an app to show a user's live location using Xamarin Forms. I am using Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMap and  geolocator plugin.I have the data like latitude and longitude of user's live location.My question is how to show /display that in a map using a an arrow ,which should turn according to the direction of user?

Comment: Look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31181086/7124761

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin Forms Maps - showing current location on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49410389/xamarin-forms-maps-showing-current-location-on-ios)

Comment: I am using geolocator plugin.I have the data like latitude and longitude of user's live location.My question is how to show /display that in a map using a an arrow ,which should turn  according to the direction of user?